# Is it possible to define a C macro in a makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

Is it possible to put the equivalent of `#define VAR` (in a C program) into a makefile, so that one can control which part of the program should be compiled?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Accordingly to `cc` manpage on `linux`

```
-D name=definition
           The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a #define directive.  In
           particular, the definition will be truncated by embedded newline characters.
```

Comment: Note that this is not Linux-specific. POSIX specifies `-D` for the `c99` command which is the standard name for the C compiler: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html

Answer (score 15):

Edit your `Makefile` to show

> CFLAGS=-D *VAR1*  -D *VAR2*=*something*

If you are using default rules in the Makefile, this should work automatically. If you do not, and are invoking the C compiler explicitely, just make sure you are writing something along the lines of

> $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Even more cute if the fact the `CFLAGS=...`above can be used on the command line rather than written in the Makefile (read `man(1)` manual page); this allows for easy reconfiguration of your compilation parameters at last moment, but the parameters won't be kept.

Best practices include using `CPPFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`, and using `+=` instead of `=`; however support for these features are not as universal as the above, and depend on your make system.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Most compilers support command line options for specifying #define's.  For Visual C++, this is the [/D option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: In fact, `-D` was used by some of the earliest C compilers, and remains nearly universally accepted. The only others I can think of that are nearly as close to universal are `-c` and maybe `-O`.

Comment: Most of Microsoft's command line tools (`cl` included) accept `/` as well as `-` as argument prefix. Which means you can use `-D` and be compatible to `cl` as well as `gcc`.