# how to set macro in makefile.am that i can used in code

Tags: makefile, macros, automake

How to set macro in makefile.am that i can used in code, e.g., `#ifdef ABC`, where the `ABC` variable is defined in makefile.am but can used in code. I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302390/is-it-possible-to-define-a-c-macro-in-a-makefile), which is talk about how to set macro in the makefile but not makefile.am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `Makefile.am` is a template for a `Makefile` (well, for `Makefile.in` which is a template for the final `Makefile`).
While automake will generate quite a lot of code in the `Makefile.am` -> `Makefile.in` translation, it will leave parts untouched, allowing you to insert your own make-code.

a typical (demo) Makefile.am would look like:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = xyz.c
foo_CPPFLAGS = -DFOO
```

which will have `FOO` defined (it adds '-DFOO' to the preprocessor flags) when compiling the `foo` program.

a more complex (and unusual) example could look like:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = xyz.c abc.c
foo_CPPFLAGS = -D@FOODEF@
```

with a configure.ac that contains something like:

```
FOODEF=KNURK
AC_SUBST(FOODEF)
```

which provides the equivalent to having `#define KNURK` in each source-file for `foo`

the above is atypical, as usually you would replace "self-contained" flags, e.g. something like, the following Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = xyz.c abc.c
foo_CPPFLAGS = @FOODEFS@ -I/usr/include/fu/
```

accompanied with a configure.ac snippet like:

```
FOODEFS=
AC_ARG_WITH([knork], AC_HELP_STRING([--with-knork=<str>], [build with knork (or frozz otherwise]))
AS_IF([test "x$with_knork" = "xyes" ],FOODEFS="-DKNORK")
AS_IF([test "x$with_knork" = "xno" ], FOODEFS="-DFROZZ")
AC_SUBST(FOODEF)
```

Answer (score 0):

The makefile itself doesn't care about your code, compiled or not. It's the compiler job.

If you use GCC you can define symbols with the -D options like this :

```
gcc -DABC=3 -o main.o main.c
```

You can of course use a Makefile variable like this :

```
DEFINED_MACRO = ABC
target.o: file.c
    gcc -D$(DEFINED_MACRO)=3 -o target.o file.c
```